# Logout session Angular2 nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, session, logout

I have an Angular2 application and NodeJS server. I got stuck on implementing logout.

If I simply use `req.session.destroy()`, it does not have any effect on the Angular2 side. Angular2 still thinks that user is logged in. (because when I call a method which returns data about logged in user, it still returns it - even though it needs req.session.user to return this data).

I saw some solutions for this problem, but all I saw was using localStorage (saving user in localStorage and then deleting it after clicking logout).

Is there any other more efficient way to tell Angular2 from NodeJS that the user has logged out and that the session has ended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use web token for user validation for instance then it should be possible to reset the token to null once the user has logged out. 
You could have a look at [User Authentication using JWT](https://devdactic.com/restful-api-user-authentication-1/) for ideas on implementation